# System.IO.IOException "Function not implemented" in CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run()

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

When I start debugging my app in a Linux Docker container, I get the exception when calling **CreateHostBuilder(args).Build()**.  The code is part of a pretty new AspASP.NET Core MVC 3.1 project.

I saw the issue before <s>and maybe fixed it removing an orphan file in a Views sub-folder</s>.  The problem seemed to come back after switching branches in git.  It happened a third time after renaming a cshtml file in my project.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
```

**Exception**

```
System.IO.IOException
  HResult=0x00000026
  Message=Function not implemented
  Source=System.IO.FileSystem
  StackTrace:
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1.CreateDirectoryHandle(String path, Boolean ignoreNotFound)
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1.Init()
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1..ctor(String directory, Boolean isNormalized, EnumerationOptions options)
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerable`1..ctor(String directory, FindTransform transform, EnumerationOptions options, Boolean isNormalized)
   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerableFactory.UserDirectories(String directory, String expression, EnumerationOptions options)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalEnumeratePaths(String path, String searchPattern, SearchTarget searchTarget, EnumerationOptions options)
   at System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories(String path)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.RunningInstance.AddDirectoryWatchUnlocked(WatchedDirectory parent, String directoryName)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.RunningInstance.AddDirectoryWatchUnlocked(WatchedDirectory parent, String directoryName)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.RunningInstance.AddDirectoryWatchUnlocked(WatchedDirectory parent, String directoryName)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.RunningInstance.AddDirectoryWatchUnlocked(WatchedDirectory parent, String directoryName)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.RunningInstance..ctor(FileSystemWatcher watcher, SafeFileHandle inotifyHandle, String directoryPath, Boolean includeSubdirectories, NotifyFilters notifyFilters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEvents()
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEventsIfNotDisposed()
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.set_EnableRaisingEvents(Boolean value)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.PhysicalFilesWatcher.TryEnableFileSystemWatcher()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.PhysicalFilesWatcher.CreateFileChangeToken(String filter)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider.Watch(String filter)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.<.ctor>b__1_0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.ChangeTokenRegistration`1..ctor(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action`1 changeTokenConsumer, TState state)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.OnChange(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action changeTokenConsumer)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider..ctor(FileConfigurationSource source)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationSource.Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.BuildAppConfiguration()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at FieldViewAdminHub.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

**I Tried**

- Executing a Clean
- Deleting obj and bin folders
- Stopping the docker container explicitly

Comment: Andy I tried stepping the code and it just worked.  Then I tried debugging again and it just worked.

Comment: Is this is a docker compose project ? are you visual studio 2017 or 2019 ?

Comment: No, this is an asp.net-core-mvc project.  I am just using Visual Studio's built-in debug in docker.

Comment: Note: The issue came back after switching some files around, but if I roll-back the changes (using git reset), it's still crashing.

Comment: I have noticed that this issue happens when i change file in the project directory without stopping the debugging first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [the answer by @AnGG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63494338/270155), I just **restarted Docker for Windows** (I did not want to prune right now).

Comment: The error happened for the third time when I renamed a cshtml files and this did the trick immediately.

Comment: I added a cshtml file manually (an editor template) and this error happened... I restarted Docker as well and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

Try ( be careful with those )

1. stop all the running containers
2. `docker system prune` ( be careful, this may remove all unused containers, networks, images (both dangling and unreferenced), and optionally, volumes. )
3. `docker system prune -a` ( be careful, this may remove all unused containers, networks, images (both dangling and unreferenced), and optionally, volumes. )
4. `docker volume prune` ( be careful, this may remove all volumes. )
5. restart docker
6. docker project clean
7. delete `bin` and `obj` folders inside the project folder
8. docker project rebuild

try to debug again

Answer (score -1):

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });


public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
```

Hi,
Please try to add this right after your code. And write the second to Startup. It will be constructor. And one more thing, check your libraries and be sure to have configuration extension.
I think your problem is your function don't have a mission.
This way you are pathing your startup and having a default host. Basicly. Hope it works. Have a nice day.

Comment: These functions already exist in the code - they were part of the new-project template in vs2019.