# Can't start Curity Identity Server using Docker

Tags: curity

I'm attempting to run the Curity Identity Server Docker image with the following command: `docker run -it -e PASSWORD=password -p 6749:6749 -p 8443:8443 curity.azurecr.io/curity/idsvr`. However, anytime I run it, it fails to start with the following error:

```
[33mse.curity.identityserver.web.AbstractRouter - Top-level Router unable to handle error as it could not obtain a RouteHandler or a ResponseRenderer. Setting response status to 404 without any response body.
[m java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Function not implemented
    at se.curity.identityserver.localization.ReloadableMessageProviderMap$ResourceDirectoriesReloader.<init>(ReloadableMessageProviderMap.java:181) ~[identityserver.core-6.4.0-ea61087d50.jar:6.4.0-ea61087d50]
    at se.curity.identityserver.localization.ReloadableMessageProviderMap.<init>(ReloadableMessageProviderMap.java:72) ~[identityserver.core-6.4.0-ea61087d50.jar:6.4.0-ea61087d50]
    at se.curity.identityserver.localization.ReloadableMessageProviderMapFactoryInjector.getComponentInstance(ReloadableMessageProviderMapFactoryInjector.java:33) ~[identityserver.core-6.4.0-ea61087d50.jar:6.4.0-ea61087d50]
    at se.curity.identityserver.localization.ReloadableMessageProviderMapFactoryInjector.getComponentInstance(ReloadableMessageProviderMapFactoryInjector.java:23) ~[identityserver.core-6.4.0-ea61087d50.jar:6.4.0-ea61087d50]
    at io.curity.femto.injectors.FactoryInjector.getComponentInstance(FactoryInjector.java:101) ~[femto-container-2.3.0.jar:?]
    at io.curity.femto.util.CyclicDependencyGuard.observe(CyclicDependencyGuard.java:55) ~[femto-container-2.3.0.jar:?]
    at io.curity.femto.ComponentAdapter.getComponentInstanceGuarded(ComponentAdapter.java:83) ~[femto-container-2.3.0.jar:?]
    at io.curity.femto.ComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentAdapter.java:62) ~[femto-container-2.3.0.jar:?]
    at io.curity.femto.GlobalComponentAdapter$FullGlobalComponentAdapter.lambda$getComponentInstance$0(GlobalComponentAdapter.java:82) ~[femto-container-2.3.0.jar:?]
    at io.curity.femto.util.SetOnceAtomicReference.get(SetOnceAtomicReference.java:43) ~[femto-container-2.3.0.jar:?]
    at io.curity.femto.GlobalComponentAdapter$FullGlobalComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(GlobalComponentAdapter.java:82) ~[femto-container-2.3.0.jar:?]
    at io.curity.femto.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getParameterInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:321) ~[femto-container-2.3.0.jar:?]
    at io.curity.femto.injectors.ConstructorInjector.access$100(ConstructorInjector.java:76) ~[femto-container-2.3.0.jar:?]
    at io.curity.femto.injectors.ConstructorInjector$SatisfiedConstructor.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:395) ~[femto-container-2.3.0.jar:?]
    at io.curity.femto.injectors.ConstructorInjector$SatisfiedConstructor.createInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:403) ~[femto-container-2.3.0.jar:?]
    at io.curity.femto.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:97) ~[femto-container-2.3.0.jar:?]
    at io.curity.femto.util.CyclicDependencyGuard.observe(CyclicDependencyGuard.java:55) ~[femto-container-2.3.0.jar:?]
    at io.curity.femto.ComponentAdapter.getComponentInstanceGuarded(ComponentAdapter.java:83) ~[femto-container-2.3.0.jar:?]
    at io.curity.femto.ComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentAdapter.java:62) ~[femto-container-2.3.0.jar:?]
    at io.curity.femto.ContainerCachingComponentAdapter.lambda$getComponentInstance$0(ContainerCachingComponentAdapter.java:26) ~[femto-container-2.3.0.jar:?]
    at io.curity.femto.util.SetOnceAtomicReference.get(SetOnceAtomicReference.java:43) ~[femto-container-2.3.0.jar:?]
    at io.curity.femto.ContainerCachingComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ContainerCachingComponentAdapter.java:26) ~[femto-container-2.3.0.jar:?]
    at io.curity.femto.DefaultFemtoContainer.getComponent(DefaultFemtoContainer.java:95) ~[femto-container-2.3.0.jar:?]
    at se.curity.identityserver.web.AbstractRouter.getRouteHandlerSafely(AbstractRouter.java:268) ~[identityserver.core-6.4.0-ea61087d50.jar:6.4.0-ea61087d50]
    at se.curity.identityserver.web.AbstractRouter.handleRoutingError(AbstractRouter.java:73) ~[identityserver.core-6.4.0-ea61087d50.jar:6.4.0-ea61087d50]
    at se.curity.identityserver.web.AdminApiRouter.handle(AdminApiRouter.java:174) ~[identityserver.admin-6.4.0-ea61087d50.jar:6.4.0-ea61087d50]
    at se.curity.identityserver.web.AdminApiRouter.handle(AdminApiRouter.java:117) ~[identityserver.admin-6.4.0-ea61087d50.jar:6.4.0-ea61087d50]
    at se.curity.identityserver.app.RequestReceiver.doFilter(RequestReceiver.java:170) ~[identityserver.core-6.4.0-ea61087d50.jar:6.4.0-ea61087d50]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233) ~[jetty-server-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1434) ~[jetty-server-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188) ~[jetty-server-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186) ~[jetty-server-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1349) ~[jetty-server-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) ~[jetty-server-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:234) ~[jetty-server-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127) ~[jetty-server-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516) ~[jetty-server-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388) ~[jetty-server-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633) ~[jetty-server-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380) ~[jetty-server-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277) ~[jetty-server-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311) ~[jetty-io-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105) ~[jetty-io-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:555) ~[jetty-io-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:410) ~[jetty-io-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:164) ~[jetty-io-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105) ~[jetty-io-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104) ~[jetty-io-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338) ~[jetty-util-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315) ~[jetty-util-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173) ~[jetty-util-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131) ~[jetty-util-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:386) ~[jetty-util-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883) ~[jetty-util-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034) ~[jetty-util-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:9.4.43.v20210629]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Function not implemented
    at sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystem.newWatchService(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at se.curity.identityserver.filesystem.DirectoryEventWatcher.<init>(DirectoryEventWatcher.java:101) ~[identityserver.core-6.4.0-ea61087d50.jar:6.4.0-ea61087d50]
    at se.curity.identityserver.localization.ReloadableMessageProviderMap$ResourceDirectoriesReloader.<init>(ReloadableMessageProviderMap.java:176) ~[identityserver.core-6.4.0-ea61087d50.jar:6.4.0-ea61087d50]
    ... 59 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this one before, but I found a post that suggests this could have to do with docker for windows having some problems. Could that be the case here? Poster restarted the docker service to make it work.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63494744/12470117

Comment: I tried restarting Docker, but it still failed to start. BTW, this is on an M1 Mac.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the emulation of the filesystem for the M1 macs, so currently its not working. We're working on getting it fixed. Currently, the workaround would be to install the tar-ball in a VM.

Comment: I'm also seeing this issue on a M1 Mac. Has a fix/workaround been identified yet?

Comment: No, running the curity container on M1's is not supported yet. Its being worked on, most likely it will be released with the 7.0 release. @ChrisBarlow